# How to refresh <Redirect to='/...'> react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm having a ton of difficulty finding the answer. Right now all my

`<Route exact path='/' render={()=><Redirect to='/dashboard'/>}/>`

does is change the url to ".../dashboard", but it doesn't refresh the page so that the component loads, only when I hit refresh does my component load.

**How can I get `<Redirect ... />` to refresh the page after redirect?**

I have had success with `window.location.reload()`, but I don't know how to put it in. I've also tried adding `<Redirect push to=.../>` without luck.

Comment: do you want to redirect always when somene lands on `/` to `/dashboard`?

Comment: `{(auth.isAuthenticated()) ? <Redirect from='/' to='/dashboard/home' />
                            :<Redirect from='/' to='/login'/>}` is the code I just tried (so no), however it breaks the auth0, the /login doesn't render the login component if I add this redirect

Comment: What is your `react-router-dom` version ?

Answer (score 1):

setup a switch route and a `Redirect`  component

```
    <Switch>
      <Redirect from='/' to='/dashboard'/>
      <Route path='/dashboard' render={(props) => (
    auth.isAuthenticated === true
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to='/login' />
  )} 
/>
</Switch>
```

More on the [docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md#from-string)

Comment: Saddly I need to render because I need to pass props through. I tried this code for the redirect without luck: `{(auth.isAuthenticated()) ? <Redirect from='/' to='/dashboard/home' />
                            :<Redirect from='/' to='/login'/>}`

Comment: So, I can't use the component option you just used (although I think that makes sure it loads correctly, I need to pass the props to it though).

Comment: i updated the answer with a mix of both, one redirects always, the other check for auth

Answer (score 1):

For `react-router-dom` v6. The below code is working for me,

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import Dashboard from './Components/Dashboard';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/dashboard" />} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```